# RuntimeWarning: invalid value warning sklearn GraphicalLassoCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, covariance, lasso-regression

I keep encountering this RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in (subtract or multiple, or divide etc) when trying to run the sklearn GraphicalLassoCV model. I checked my dataframe to make sure that it is free of any NaN or Inf values that could be causing this, but my data is free of them and I can't find anything in it that would be causing these warning messages. Any help or ideas with what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated Screenshot of my code and the error messages: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndG0t.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndG0t.png)